# How to fetch transaction details for Logs Table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I want to create a tracking table for changes made to the database.

A tracking table called `Logs` must be created into which all changes (`insert` and `delete`) that are made in the database will be entered on the following tables:

```
Author, Publisher, Chapter
```

The columns of the `Logs` table will be:

```
  DateOfLog (DateTime)
  ActionType (varchar (15))
  LogTable (varchar (15))
  ActionData (nvarchar (max))
```

I have created the Logs Table as well as writing a trigger to load information in `Logs`, but the problem is with `LogTable` and `ActionData` columns.

Let me know that how to get the name of table on which action performed and the data in string that got affected.

Effort made yet is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Logs (DateOfLog, ActionType, LogTable, ActionData)
    SELECT
       GETDATE(),
       CASE WHEN I.ID IS NULL THEN 'DELETE' END,
   FROM
       DELETED D
   LEFT JOIN
       INSERTED I ON D.ID = I.ID
```

Comment: The is far too broad. Your question is effectively "please help me", which isn't an answerable question.

Comment: *"how to get the name of table"* you create a trigger on a specific object, so you already know what the name of that object is when you create it. `CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger_Ins ON dbo.MyTable AFTER INSERT...` The table's name is `MyTable` on the schema `dbo`.

Comment: You may be better off creating distinct triggers for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE. But to know which columns are affected in an update can only be done by querying the state of the data before it is modified. This can be done with triggers that fire BEFORE the data is changed.

Comment: @Fleshy you can tell what columns were effected **after** by using the `deleted` object; which contains the values of the rows **before** the update (so you could compare against `inserted`). There is no such things as a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger in SQL Server; you only have `AFTER` and `INSTEAD OF`.

Comment: You also have the `IF UPDATE ({Column Name})` syntax if you want to check a specific column for the logical flow of the trigger.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks you solved my problem :)